# How to get python to ask for values (lat lon or SPC) for line intersection problem and how to print coordinates of intersection point

Tags: python, line, intersection

A question was asked at

[Intersections between Geodesics (shortest distance paths) on the surface of a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668041/intersections-between-geodesics-shortest-distance-paths-on-the-surface-of-a-sp/57328646#57328646)

The questioner asked for if two lines crossed, the answer said "true" then the questioner pointed out that he also wanted the coordinates of where the intersection was.

Given the above code how can I input the two lines and how can i print out the solution. And what is the environment this code applies to? (plane trig? geodesic elipsoidal, spherical?

see

[Intersections between Geodesics (shortest distance paths) on the surface of a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668041/intersections-between-geodesics-shortest-distance-paths-on-the-surface-of-a-sp/57328646#57328646)

Comment: This is really unclear: you've found a question using Python to solve a geometry problem. It has an answer. You posted a second answer on that question in a completely different language. You post this question. Which code do you need help with? The code from the question, the code from the accepted answer, or the code from your answer?

Comment: If you examined the link the person who asked the question did not receive the answer he (and I) wanted.  We want to know where the two lines cross not just wheather they cross.  I would also like to know how to specify the two lines, I am brand new to python. given the code I cant figure how the two lines are specified. I have figured out a solution using plane trig but I would like an answer that uses elipsoidal geodesic lines, or at least spherical trig.

Comment: I think the code in that question is incomplete, and hence the lines aren't really specified. Normally you'd have an `__init__` function as part of a class whose job it is to set the class up. In this case something like `def __init__(self,point1,point2): self.point1 = point1; self.point2 = point2`. Then call `_SecondaryInitialization`. However, there's a lot of detail missing that just isn't given and can probably only be guessed at.